# How to convert this SQL query to Django Queryset?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have this query which selects values from two different tables and used array agg over matched IDs how can I get same results using the queryset. Thank you!

```
select
    sf.id_s2_users ,
    array_agg(sp.id)
from
    s2_followers sf
left join s2_post sp on
    sp.id_s2_users = sf.id_s2_users1
where
    sp.id_s2_post_status = 1
    and sf.id_s2_user_status = 1
group by
    sf.id_s2_users
```

Comment: Share model code and add description of problem

Answer (score 0):

You can run raw SQL queries with Django's ORM if that's what you wanted. You don't have to change your query in that case, you can check [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries).